# Copying specific values from a dataframe into a new dataframe while transposing

Tags: python, pandas

this is my sample data of US inflation rates

[image]

With the code below I am trying to transpose the data

```
new_inflation_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['year','quarter','inflation_rate'])
for rows in inflation_df.iterrows():
    for q in range(1,5):
        new_inflation_df.at[rows+q-1, 'year'] = inflation_df.at[rows, 'YEAR']
        if q == 1:
            new_inflation_df.at[rows+q-1, 'quarter'] = 1
            new_inflation_df.at[rows+q-1, 'inflation_rate'] = inflation_df.at[rows, "MAR"]
        elif q == 2:
            new_inflation_df.at[rows+q-1, 'quarter'] = 2
            new_inflation_df.at[rows+q-1, 'inflation_rate'] = inflation_df.at[rows, "JUN"]
        elif q == 3:
            new_inflation_df.at[rows+q-1, 'quarter'] = 3
            new_inflation_df.at[rows+q-1, 'inflation_rate'] = inflation_df.at[rows, "SEP"]
        elif q == 4:
            new_inflation_df.at[rows+q-1, 'quarter'] = 4
            new_inflation_df.at[rows+q-1, 'inflation_rate'] = inflation_df.at[rows, "DEC"]
```

This is my expected output of the new_inflation_df:

[image]

but I am getting this typeerror:
can anyone assist?

> TypeError: '(0, YEAR       1914.0 JAN           2.0 FEB           1.0
> MAR             1 APR           0.0 MAY           2.1 JUN
> 1.0 JUL           1.0 AUG           3.0 SEP           2.0 OCT           1.0 NOV           1.0 DEC           1.0 AVE           1.0 Quarter         4 Name: 0, dtype: object)' is an invalid key

Comment: made a couple corrections in my code but still getting the same error.

Comment: kindly share your data as text, not pics

Comment: How are you aggregating the values of the months on the same quarter?

Comment: I am trying to copy and paste the sample data from excel but it automatically pastes as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own data. Someone with more experience with Pandas then I do  will write the code below with more finesse.

```
import pandas as pd

data=[
    [1914, 1, 1, 1, 10, 12, 11, 1, 1, 1, 10, 12, 11],
    [1916, 5, 5, 5.1, 15, 15, 20, 5, 5, 5.1, 15, 15, 20],
    [1918, 19.7, 17.5, 16.7, 1, 2, 3, 19.7, 17.5, 16.7, 1, 2, 3]
    ]
cols = ["YEAR", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"]
inflation_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols )

# create new df
new_inflation_df = pd.DataFrame()

counter = 0
for index, rows in inflation_df.iterrows():
    for q in range(1,5):
        counter += 1
        new_inflation_df.loc[counter,'year'] = inflation_df.at[index, 'YEAR']
        if q == 1:
            new_inflation_df.at[counter,'quarter'] = q
            new_inflation_df.at[counter,'inflation_rate'] = inflation_df.loc[ index, ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR']].mean()
        elif q == 2:
            new_inflation_df.at[counter,'quarter'] = q
            new_inflation_df.at[counter,'inflation_rate'] = inflation_df.loc[ index, ['APR', 'MAY', 'JUN']].mean()
        elif q == 3:
            new_inflation_df.at[counter,'quarter'] = q
            new_inflation_df.at[counter,'inflation_rate'] = inflation_df.loc[ index, ['JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP']].mean()
        elif q == 4:
            new_inflation_df.at[counter,'quarter'] = q
            new_inflation_df.at[counter,'inflation_rate'] = inflation_df.loc[ index, ['OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']].mean()

#convert year and quarter to integers
new_inflation_df['year'] = new_inflation_df['year'].astype('int')
new_inflation_df['quarter'] = new_inflation_df['quarter'].astype('int')

print(new_inflation_df)
```

Output:

```
    year  quarter  inflation_rate
1   1914        1        1.000000
2   1914        2       11.000000
3   1914        3        1.000000
4   1914        4       11.000000
5   1916        1        5.033333
6   1916        2       16.666667
7   1916        3        5.033333
8   1916        4       16.666667
9   1918        1       17.966667
10  1918        2        2.000000
11  1918        3       17.966667
12  1918        4        2.000000
```